# Low EPS export quality for Histogram/BarChart

Tags: graphics, export, charts, histograms, eps-format

I like to export a figure as an EPS and continue to edit it afterwards (e.g., with inkscape). In the past, I was only exporting plots and everything worked fine: figures had high quality, and I could select and modify individual features with a vector graphics editor.

Now, things change drastically with histograms or bar charts. Exporting them as EPS makes the bars look ugly (e.g., the same bar has at different places a different line thickness), and it is not possible to modify the individual bars using a vector graphics editor. Here is a screenshot of the EPS:

[image]

I hope I do not need to post any code because this happens just with any Histogram/BarChart that I tested (as long as it is a little complex and contains more than, say, 3 or 4 values). Where is the problem here? How can one export it "nicely"?

Moreover, what I actually want to export and modify is something of the form Show[Histogram,Plot]. In Mathematica the output looks just fine, but again I had no success with exporting it in EPS format.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: As an alternative—and what works for me when doing subsequent editing in Inkscape—is to export .svg or .pdf.   Both give vector graphics.

Comment: That's it, indeed! Many thanks! I feel very stupid now, trying it for hours with EPS. I wonder how much time humans waste by not questioning their premises... :-/